# Do you have nerves on the outside of your skull?

Tags: human-biology

I have a spot on my skull that feels like a nerve or blood vessel. I know that there are many to the brain, however, it is the only one I have ever felt. So do we have nerves or blood vessels on the top or outside of the skull?

Comment: Are you talking about the surface of your skull, or anything/everything "outer" to it? If there were no nerve (endings) or blood vessels outside the skull, there would be no pain or bleeding with, say, scalp lacerations or hard bumps. So wording needs to be more specific. Generally the nerves and blood vessels of the scalp aren't easily palpable. Might you be feeling a skull suture line?

Comment: A soft or hard spot (bump) on the skull part of the head can be also a skin cyst or lipoma, for example. The nerves are flat and I'm not sure if you can really feel them. From vessels you would probably more likely feel the veins than arteries.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of nuerovascular bundles that exit the skull. Three involve branches of the [trigeminal nerve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigeminal_nerve).